# dplyr conditional summarise function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this situation where I need a different summary **function** based on a condition. 
For example, using iris, say for some reason I wanted the sum of the petal width if the species was setosa, otherwise I wanted the mean of the petal width.

Naively, I wrote this using case_when, which does not work:

```
iris <- tibble::as_tibble(iris)

 iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(pwz = case_when(
    Species == "setosa" ~ sum(Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE),
    TRUE                ~ mean(Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `pwz` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 50

I eventually found something like this, summarizing using each method, and then in a mutate picking which one I actually wanted:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(pws = sum(Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE),
            pwm = mean(Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(pwz = case_when(
    Species == "setosa" ~ pws,
    TRUE                ~ pwm)) %>% 
  select(-pws, -pwm)
```

But that seems more than a bit awkward with creating all these summarized values and only picking one at the end, especially when my real case_when is a lot more complicated.  Can I not use case_when inside of summarise?  Do I have my syntax wrong?  Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I suppose I should have pointed out that I have multiple conditions/functions (just assume I've got, depending on the variable, some that need mean, sum, max, min, or other summary).

Comment: Sounds like the real problem might be that your data isn't in a "tidy" format. It's very odd to perform different summarizations of values in the same column depending on other column values. You cannot use `case_when` like that because it's a vectorized function so it does not collapse (you'd only be taking the sum/mean of one value at a time).

Comment: It's in long format - environmental data observations for different variables over time (daily), by district.  I'm creating weekly summaries, but, for instance, with rainfall you need to add to get the total rainfall during that week, but for temperature, take the average during the week.  So it is probably weird, but it makes sense with this dataset.  
That's useful information about it being a non-collapsing vectorized function - that tells me _why_ my first attempt didn't work, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This is pretty easy with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
iris2 <- as.data.table(iris)

iris2[, if(Species == 'setosa') sum(Petal.Width) 
        else mean(Petal.Width)
      , by = Species]
```

More concisely, but maybe not as clear

```
iris2[, ifelse(Species == 'setosa', sum, mean)(Petal.Width)
      , by = Species]
```

With `dplyr` you can do

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(pwz = if_else(first(Species == "setosa")
                          , sum(Petal.Width)
                          , mean(Petal.Width)))
```

Note:

I'm thinking it probably makes more sense to "spread" your data with `tidyr::spread` so that each day has a column for temperature, rainfall, etc. Then you can use `summarise` in the usual way.

Comment: I thought about spreading.  My function is accepting a wide range of environmental variables, and a look up table to figure out the summary method.  I think it would be harder for me to keep track of a variable number of new columns if I `tidyr::spread`.  I think I might have simplified my problem a bit too much with my reproducible example.  I was trying to avoid multiple nested `if_else` statements (hence me trying `case_when` first), but it's still on the table as I'm trying things.  Thanks!

Comment: @michdn Yeah, I think the key, if using `dplyr`, is to just use `first` to check values when you know they're all the same. You can of course use the `first` function within `case_when` as well as `if_else`

Answer (score 2):

Why not calculate at the row level first, then summarize?

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(pwz = case_when(
      Species == "setosa" ~ sum(Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE),
      TRUE                ~ mean(Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
      summarize(pwz= first(pwz))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     Species    pwz
      <fctr>  <dbl>
1     setosa 12.300
2 versicolor  1.326
3  virginica  2.026
```

Comment: This might actually be the simplest and easier thing for me to do.  I have my set of case_when situations already semi-coded from when I trying this the first time.  It's pretty straight-forward, which is good, since I'll be passing this code to someone else down the line.  I've got a project meeting tomorrow, we'll see what the other coders on my team think.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like this if you want to put everything in the summarise function.  But it's no less complicated than your original workaround:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(pwz = 
    sum(Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE)*
    (1/n()*mean(Species != "setosa") + 
     mean(Species == "setosa")))
```

Comment: Ha, that's inventive.  I'd pity the person who has to maintain my code after me though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
data(iris)
library(dplyr)

sum_species <- c('setosa')

iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>% 
   summarise(pwz_sum = sum(Petal.Width, na.rm=T), 
             pwz_mean= mean(Petal.Width, na.rm=T)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   mutate(pwz = if_else(Species %in% sum_species, pwz_sum, pwz_mean))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the idea of splitting out the variables into lists (for sum, mean, etc.)  I did toy with this for a while, since I have a unknown & variable number of environmental variables (my data) that I'm summarizing in my function.  I still have the problem that I'm creating all the different types of summaries for all of them though, though I might just have to accept that as an intermediate step.

Comment: You could create a new function using `switch` for summary purposes. Something like: `switch(Species, setosa = sum(...), species2 = mean(...), species3=foo(...), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You could split your `data.frame` and then use `map2_dfr` to apply a different function on each part and stitch the results back together:

```
library(tidyverse) # purrr & dplyr
iris %>%
  arrange(Species=="setosa") %>%
  split(.,.$Species=="setosa") %>%
  map2_dfr(c(mean,sum),~.x %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize_at("Petal.Width",.y))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# Species Petal.Width
#       <fctr>       <dbl>
# 1 versicolor       1.326
# 2  virginica       2.026
# 3     setosa      12.300
```

Comment: oh, I think if I understood purrr functions better this could have worked nicely for me.  I'm actually doing a whole bunch of dplyr programming / new functions, and I don't know which species (in my code, environmental variables) I'll be getting ahead of time, so I can't hard code anything.  I've got a look up table, I bet I could've used it to  split and map appropriately to do the summary.  I've not used any functions in purrr yet, but I'll give it a try, thank you very much!

Comment: If you understand `lapply` and `Map` you'll understand the `purrr::map` family in no time. To parametrize my function just have to replace "setosa" by x and "Petal.Width" by y.